# Grouping data by columns

Tags: sql, group-by, pivot

I have a data set like this:

```
 id_tecnico                             dia  hora total
   <chr>                                <dbl> <int> <int>
 1 0011ab4f-6871-40f4-91f2-818e309baa41     8    13     1
 2 0011ab4f-6871-40f4-91f2-818e309baa41    45    10     1
 3 0011ab4f-6871-40f4-91f2-818e309baa41    46     9     1
 4 0011ab4f-6871-40f4-91f2-818e309baa41    50    14     1
 5 0011ab4f-6871-40f4-91f2-818e309baa41    58    12     1
 6 0011ab4f-6871-40f4-91f2-818e309baa41    70    12     1
 7 0011ab4f-6871-40f4-91f2-818e309baa41    81    11     1
 8 0011ab4f-6871-40f4-91f2-818e309baa41    86    11     1
 9 0011ab4f-6871-40f4-91f2-818e309baa41    89     9     1
10 0011ab4f-6871-40f4-91f2-818e309baa41    92    11     1
```

I would like to group the data the column `total` by `hour`, but I would like the result by column, not by row, creating a new column for each hour sum : `hour1`, `hour2`, `hour3`...

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you format your data so that it is in a much more readable style (like aligned columns with the values)...

Comment: Also provide an example of what is the look of the result that you're trying to achieve

Comment: Day hour9 hour10 hour11 hour12 hour13 hour14
8     1 
45  1    
46 1     
50      1
58    1  
70    1  
81   1   
86   1   
89 1     
92   1

Comment: @CristhianSilva Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58938103/edit) and add that information in the post directly, not as a comment.